# Pyodide filesystem for NLTK resources : missing files

Tags: filesystems, nltk, webassembly, pyodide

I am trying to use [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) in browser, thanks to [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/).
Pyodide starts well, manages to load NLTK, print its version.

Nevertheless, while the package downloading seems fine, when invoking `nltk.sent_tokenize(str)`, NLTK raises the error that it can't find the package "punkt".

I would say the downloaded resource is lost somewhere, but I didn't understand well how Pyodide / WebAssembly manage files. Any insights ?

[image: Screenshot of the error: "Resource punkt not found. Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle. Searched in: - '/nltk_data'"]

Simple version:

```py
import nltk
nltk.download(pkg)
for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize("Test string"):
    print(sent)
```

Version with more details, specifying download directory and server url.

```py
import nltk
pkg = "punkt"
downloader = nltk.downloader.Downloader(server_index_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml") 
downloader.download(pkg, download_dir='/nltk_data')
downloader.status(pkg)
for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize("Test string"):
    print(sent)
```

Full sample code:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // init Pyodide
      async function pyodide_loader() {
        let pyodide_premise = loadPyodide({
          indexURL: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.0/full/",
        });
        let pyodide = await pyodide_premise;
        await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip");
        await pyodide.loadPackage("nltk");
        return pyodide_premise;
      }
      let pyodideReadyPromise = pyodide_loader();

      
      // run Python code and load NLTK
      async function load_packages() {
        let pyodide = await pyodideReadyPromise;
        let output = pyodide.runPython(`
print(f"*** import nltk")
import nltk
print(f"*** NLTK version {nltk.__version__=} imported, downloading resources now")

pkg = "punkt"
nltk.download(pkg)

str = "Just for testing"
for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(str):
    print(sent)
      `);
      }
      load_packages()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is that downloading files with Python currently won't work in Pyodide because `http.client`, `requests` etc require POSIX sockets which are not supported in the browser VM.

It's curious that `nltk.download` doesn't error though -- it should have.

The workaround is to manually download the needed resources, for instance, using the JavaScript [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) as illustrated in [this comment](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/400#issuecomment-882101102);

```py
from js import fetch

response = await fetch("<url>")
js_buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
py_buffer = js_buffer.to_py()  # this is a memoryview
stream = py_buffer.tobytes()  # now we have a bytes object

# that we can finally write under the appropriate path
with open("<file_path>", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(stream)
```

> I didn't understand well how Pyodide / WebAssembly manage files.

By default it's virtual file-system ([MEMFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#memfs)) that gets reset at each page load. You can access it with standard python tools (`open`, 'os', etc). If necessary you can also [mount a persistent filesystem](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/pull/1596).

Comment: When I try to replicate, I get an error at `nltk.download`.

Comment: I managed to solve it by downloading the files, with js.window.fetch. Thanks !

Comment: How do you await a function in Pyodide ? I always run into issues like `RuntimeWarning: coroutine '<async_function>' was never awaited`.

Comment: I was using `pyodide.runPython()` instead of the *async* version `pyodide.runPythonAsync()`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example of loading `punkt` with `pyodide` v0.18.1. I tried to post this as a comment to @rth's accepted answer, but the number of characters exceeded the 240 chars limit.

```py
from js import fetch
import nltk
from pathlib import Path
import os, sys, io, zipfile

response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip')
js_buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
py_buffer = js_buffer.to_py()  # this is a memoryview
stream = py_buffer.tobytes()  # now we have a bytes object

d = Path("/nltk_data/tokenizers")
d.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

Path('/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt.zip').write_bytes(stream)

# extract punkt.zip
zipfile.ZipFile('/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt.zip').extractall(
    path='/nltk_data/tokenizers/'
)

# check file contents in /nltk_data/tokenizers/
# print(os.listdir("/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt"))

nltk.word_tokenize("some text here")
```

I received a lot of help from the `pyodide` maintainers and other wonderful people at https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/1798 to figure this out. Thanks!